# Node.js Kill app because of memory usage

Tags: node.js

I have simple app

its a for loop going through a request rest api and then go to another for loop and request.

something like this :

```
var request = require('request');

for(var j=1;j<=10;j++){

            request({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'https://api.domain.com/items/?page='+j+'&limit=1000',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }}, function (error, response, body) {

              var data = JSON.parse(body)


              for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                    request({
                      method: 'GET',
                      url: 'https://api.domain.com/itemDetail/'+data[i].id,
                      headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      }}, function (error, response, body) {


                        var itemDetails = JSON.parse(body);

                        // save items to mongodb          

                        }

              }
    });

}
```

i have more than 200,000 data to save , when i loop through 10 page (set first loop limit to 10) its ok but when i increase the page number in first loop node memory usage going high and kill app.

i wants know the reason this happen and how solve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: You will want to control how many requests are "in-flight" at the same time from both loops.  Both the Async library and the Bluebird promise library have functions specifically for doing this.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, can you give me an example?

Comment: Do you understand the concept I'm talking about?  If so, what specific question do you have about implementing it?  In the Async library, you would use the `.eachLimit()` method.  In the Bluebird library, you could use the `.map()` method with the concurrency option or you can code it yourself with a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to trigger 200'000 item to save, iterating through a loop means you will ask your javascript application to keep waiting for thousands of callbacks to return and finish. This is not going to work, remember that javascript (and thus nodejs) are single-threaded.

You should implement this routine with a library like `async` or `q`, which give you control over the iteration cycle to keep it within acceptable memory limits.

Comment: could you give me an example for `async` in my situation i should use `series` ?

Comment: Can't give an example right now, I'm on the go. But the best you can do is read the async documentation itself, it's really good and will teach you tons about how to properly use this module. If I were you, I'd look at eachLimit instead of series. Series will execute the commands sequentially, which is probably not what you want. You want some parallelism without crashing the system